# Nested list vertical alignment in beamer

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, itemize

I have a nested item list of large bold text in beamer.
Somehow, it looks like the vertical alignment of the items of the top level list is incorrect, as the item containing the nested list is too close to the previous item.

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Bold}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}
    \begin{Large}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Give you up
            \item Let you down
            \item Never gonna
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Run around
                    \item And
                    \item Desert you
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{Large}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the result :

[image: result]

I would expect the top level elements to be equally spaced, but element 3 is too close from element 2.
What is causing this problem ? What are the possible solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy solution: just finish the paragraph by inserting an empty line. Without the new paragraph, the smaller line spacing from your subitem font will be used.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test}

    \begingroup
        \Large
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Give you up
            \item Let you down
            \item Never gonna
            
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Run around
                    \item And
                    \item Desert you
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
        \endgroup    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Large` is not environment but switch. i would consider changing line spacing s as bug.

Comment: @Zarko Oh my! How could I miss this?

Comment: Just curious... why not  `submitem`?

Comment: @SalJr Because it is beamer and not a normal document. `subitem` would result in an undefined control sequence error.